# Dynamic plots in HTML

Tags: html, plot, movie

I have been developing a software package to plot astronomical data in the form of a movie. It looks like [this](http://cs.oswego.edu/~ebelling/research/aas/).

To do this, I export 100 tables of data from Java to gnuplot and use a bash script to turn them into a GIF. I want instead to do it in HTML and maybe [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html).

I'm thinking that I can use a Python script to iterate through folders and build a hundred plots, and then cycle through them. Any ideas on this? How can I get them to cycle?

Comment: what do the tables look like?

Comment: They're just lists of x,y coordinates for each of the data points you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to test performance issues, but FLOT might be just the thing for you...

here is an example of flot animating:
http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/realtime.html

Answer (score 1):

I think a canvas is what you need.  Just draw all the points, clear the canvas, and redraw

your code would look something like this pseduo code

```
for each frame 
    for each point 
        canvas.draw point at x, y
    end
    clear canvas
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I was looking for something similar, I found this one link will be trying it out http://humblesoftware.com/flotr2/